# Preventing usage of Hamcrest with JUnit 4.x

Tags: java, maven, junit, hamcrest, assertj

I am currently using JUnit 4.x with AssertJ. I would like to ensure that no usages of Hamcrest sneak it. However, Hamcrest Core is a required dependency at runtime for JUnit, see [Junit issue #1429: A Exception for junit4.12 about org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing #1429](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/1429) , so excluding the dependency from the pom.xml outright or adjusting the `maven-surefire-plugin` classpath would not work.

What I am looking for is a way to adjust the test compiler classpath, but I did not find such an option in the `maven-compiler-plugin`.

How can I make sure that my tests do not use Hamcrest assertions? I would like to enforce this at build time, using Maven.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the thing that you can't exclude the transitive dependency of Hamcrest from JUnit 4 cause it's used by JUnit itself there only a few options:

- Migrate to JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5) and remove hamcrest completely and ban dependency via maven-enforcer-rule
- Using [Arch Unit](https://www.archunit.org/) to prevent the usage
- Create SonarQube Rule
- As Robert already suggest Checkstyle rule..
- Also you could think of writing a custom enforcer rule?
- Another option could be to use [JQAssistant](https://jqassistant.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Maven is missing a scope. It has `test`, but it is used for both test-compile and test-runtime. Ideally you would have set the scope of hamcrest to test-runtime. JUnit 5 already made clear Maven is missing this scope, but it is hard to introduce a new scope.

So I think the best option you have is the Checkstyle Rule [IllegalType](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_coding.html#IllegalType) or similar rules to prevent it.

Comment: Would the test-runtime not allow the usage of  Hamcrest in your test code? If I correctly understand it would not which will not solve the problem. Maybe we should think about an enforcer rule to check for imports in code?

Comment: Suppose you could change the scope of hamcrest to the non existing test-runtime, then it won't be on the classpath while compiling your tests. Hence if you are using hamcrest classes, the build would fail. I don't like the idea of enforcer-rule, because you need to analyze the (source)code. There are already frameworks that can do that, let's not reinvent that wheel.